# XML not formatted when XSL file exists

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-formatting

I have tried to display this in both Chrome and Safari. I basically took these two files out of a tutorial. However when it displays all it does is display the raw xml and it doesn't seem to read the xsl file. Both of these files are under the same directory.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
      <body>
      <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
      <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<catalog>
 <cd>
  <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
  <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
  <country>USA</country>
  <company>Columbia</company>
  <price>10.90</price>
  <year>1985</year>
 </cd>
</catalog>
```

Comment: Silly question, but have you named the XSLT file "test.xsl" (and with that capitalization)?

Comment: Haha, yes and I just checked again to make sure.

Comment: the closing `</xsl:stylesheet>` tag is missing

Comment: Oops, sorry that part didn't get included in the code block, but yea it's there. I have made the edits in the code block.

Comment: One thing I noticed when looking at the test.xsl file is that it complains about the xsl namespace which I thought I defined

Comment: Works for me (in Safari).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stylesheet: save as test.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="title" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="artist" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Html Page: Save as index.**xhtml**

```
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

place both files in the same folder.

tested in IE10.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this fixed worked for me. Saving it as .xhtml

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the base namespace (`xmlns`) in your XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works for me this way in IE, does not work without it.

Comment: Firefox will also render it correctly without that namespace.

Comment: @rdc Yea, Chrome does not display anything at all for me either way.  XSL support seems to vary quite disturbingly between the browsers.